# CSS Scroll Snapping, verticial nested elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to have a scroll snapping effect on my website, however, I'm noticing that I can't have scroll snapping because of how my elements are structured. Currently it looks like
[image]

I'm trying to make it so that the section & main inside .container have a scroll snapping effect, however since my root class handles the scrolling, the container doesn't get recognized and I'm not able to scroll.

CSS for root

```css
.root {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  position: relative;

  scroll-behavior: smooth;

  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.25rem 15.625rem;
  min-height: 100vh !important;

  background: var(--primary-background);
}
```

CSS for container

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    /* scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh); */

    main,
    section {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }

}
```